# Why does '*(veg + i)' work but '*(veg++)' does not?

Tags: c

I'm using Code::Blocks 16.01 on Raspbian Stretch for C. In the following program, when I un-comment the 'veg++' line, it doesn't run.

```
int main()
{
  char *veg[] =
    {
      "corn",
      "carrot",
      "pea"
    };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      puts(veg[i]); // this works
      puts(*(veg + i)); // this works
      //puts(*(veg++)); // this does not work
    }
return 0;
}
```

I get the build message: "....main.c|848|error: lvalue required as increment operand|"

Why is 'veg + 1' different from 'veg++'? It probably goes without saying I'm a beginner.

Comment: veg is an array. Maybe you must write i++ and not veg++

Comment: The reason the code does not compile is that it attempts to treat an array as if it were a pointer, which it is not.

Comment: veg++ is equivalent to veg = veg + 1 .You can't change the address of an array.

Comment: Even if veg were a pointer (allowing your code to compile) I think it might act differently than you expect.